John 20:23 - If Jesus can forgive sins because he is God, are we also God because we too can forgive sins?
John 20:21-23

Jesus said to them again, “Peace be with you. As the Father has sent
me, even so I am sending you.” And when he had said this, he breathed
on them and said to them, “Receive the Holy Spirit. If you forgive the
sins of any, they are forgiven them; if you withhold forgiveness from
any, it is withheld.”


Or are we and Christ able to forgive sins because God's own Spirit dwells within us, which means that God himself is inside of us and forgiving others through us as his agents?

See also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/what-did-jesus-mean-in-john-2023-when-he-talked-about-his-followers-forgiving-s/55938#55938  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/93205/john-20-21-23-are-you-referring-to-confession-by-the-priest-or-something-else/93206#93206
